# Deleting one position to another position elements from list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, element

I have a list like the one below and I would like to **delete** *all entries between any word (inclusive) and the next `'0'` (exclusive).*

So for example this list:

```
array = ['1', '1', '0', '3', '0', '2', 'Continue', '1', '5', '1', '4', '0', '7', 'test', '3', '6', '0']
```

should become:

```
['1', '1', '0', '3', '0', '2', '0', '7', '0']
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Great! Good luck with that! If you get stuck, ask a question with what you've tried and researched. Read [ask] for more guidelines

Comment: bool_digit = True
indexOfZero = 0
indexOfWord = 0
for key in array:
    if key.isdigit():
        print(key)
    else:
        indexOfWord = array.index(key)
        bool_digit = False
    if key == "0":
        indexOfZero = array.index(key)
    if indexOfZero > indexOfWord:
        bool_digit = True
    while bool_digit:
        print(key)
        bool_digit = False

Comment: Please edit your question by placing the code your have so far and keep from posting it in the comment section.

Comment: @Steffi Keran Rani J

Comment: @kamcode Edit your question by including the code snippet you have tried

Comment: @SteffiKeranRaniJ Got the answer. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it by using exclusively `list comprehension`:

```
array = ['1', '1', '0', '3', '0', '2', 'Continue', '1', '5', '1', '4', '0', '7', 'test', '3', '6', '0']

# Find indices of strings in list
alphaIndex = [i for i in range(len(array)) if any(k.isalpha() for k in array[i])] 

# Find indices of first zero following each string
zeroIndex = [array.index('0',i) for i in alphaIndex] 

# Create a list with indices to be `blacklisted`
zippedIndex = [k for i,j in zip(alphaIndex, zeroIndex) for k in range(i,j)] 

# Filter the original list
array = [i for j,i in enumerate(array) if j not in zippedIndex] 

print(array)
```

Output:

```
['1', '1', '0', '3', '0', '2', '0', '7', '0']
```

Comment: is the words are 'Skip-True' like this this can't done... I mean for isalpha need only words. Here it should be if there is any character the above process should happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ['1', '1', '0', '3', '0', '2', 'Continue', '1', '5', '1', '4', '0', '7', 'test', '3', '6', '0']

res = []
skip = False      #Flag to skip elements after a word
for i in array:
    if not skip:
        if i.isalpha():   #Check if element is alpha
            skip = True
            continue
        else:
            res.append(i)
    else:
        if i.isdigit():   #Check if element is digit
            if i == '0':
                res.append(i)
                skip = False

print res
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '1', '0', '3', '0', '2', '0', '7', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Kicking it old school -

```
array = ['1', '1', '0', '3', '0', '2', 'Continue', '1', '5', '1', '4', '0', '7', 'test', '3', '6', '0']
print(array)
array_op = []
i=0
while i < len(array):
    if not array[i].isdigit():
        i = array[i:].index('0')+i
        continue
    array_op.append(array[i])
    i += 1
print(array_op)
```

Comment: It is not the right way to give '0' in index. It will break if array[i:] does not hold '0' value.